# While upgrading to Lit 3.1.1 from Lit 2.2.5, it gives me the below error while browsing

Tags: lit

The issue seems to be in @lit\decorators\property.js.  It complains at the same file that e.constructor.createProperty is not a function.  I am going to paste the entire code below, please help me find out the details of the errors.

```
    Uncaught TypeError: e.constructor.createProperty is not a function
        at property.js:6:682
        at property.js:6:768
        at Object.decorateElement (property.js:6:776)
        at Object.<anonymous> (property.js:6:776)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at Object.decorateClass (property.js:6:776)
        at _decorate (property.js:6:776)
        at simple-element.ts:5:27
        at app.ts:7:122
```

My files have the following entries

```
    // babel.config.json
    {
        "plugins": [
          ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", {"version": "2023-05"}]
        ]
    }
```

```
    //package.json
    {
        "name": "scg-envoy-litelement",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "",
        "types": "dist/types/index.d.ts",
        "author": "Jonathan Pong",
        "license": "ISC",
        "dependencies": {
            "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.8.0",
            "lit": "^3.1.1",
            "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
            "whatwg-fetch": "^3.6.20"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "@babel/core": "^7.23.7",
            "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.23.3",
            "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.23.5",
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.18.6",
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.23.7",
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.18.6",
            "@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions": "^7.23.3",
            "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.8",
            "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
            "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.23.8",
            "@open-wc/eslint-config": "^12.0.3",
            "@open-wc/rollup-plugin-html": "^1.2.5",
            "@rollup/plugin-babel": "^6.0.4",
            "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^25.0.7",
            "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
            "@rollup/plugin-terser": "^0.4.4",
            "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "11.1.6",
            "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.18.1",
            "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.18.1",
            "concurrently": "^8.2.2",
            "core-js": "^3.35.0",
            "eslint": "^8.56.0",
            "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
            "eslint-plugin-babel": "^5.3.1",
            "eslint-plugin-html": "^7.1.0",
            "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.29.1",
            "eslint-plugin-lit": "^1.11.0",
            "eslint-plugin-lit-a11y": "^4.1.1",
            "eslint-plugin-no-only-tests": "^3.1.0",
            "eslint-plugin-wc": "^2.0.4",
            "http-server": "^14.1.1",
            "picomatch": "^3.0.1",
            "rimraf": "^5.0.5",
            "rollup": "^4.9.4",
            "tslib": "^2.6.2",
            "typescript": "^5.3.3"
        },
        "scripts": {
            "inst": "npm install && npm run build:types && npm run build:js",
            "clean": "rimraf ./out",
            "format": "eslint --ext .ts,.html . --fix",
            "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.html .",
            "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
            "type-check:watch": "npm run type-check -- --watch",
            "build:types": "tsc --emitDeclarationOnly",
            "build:js": "rollup -c",
            "build": "npm run build:types && npm run build:js",
            "rebuild": "npm run clean && npm run build",
            "server": "concurrently --kill-others --names tsc,http-server \"http-server\"",
            "depcheck": "depcheck"
        },
        "eslintConfig": {
            "extends": [
                "@open-wc/eslint-config",
                "eslint-config-prettier"
            ]
        },
        "prettier": {
            "singleQuote": true,
            "arrowParens": "avoid"
        }
    }
```

```
    //rollup.config.mjs
    import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
    import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
    import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
    import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';

    const extensions = ['.js', '.ts', '.html'];
    const prod = false;

    function output() {
      const output = {
        dir: 'dist',
        format: 'iife',
        sourcemap: true,
      };
      prod && (output.plugins = [terser()]);
      return output;
    }

    export default {
      input: ['src/app.ts'],
      strictDeprecations: true,
      output: output(),
      plugins: [
        resolve({ extensions, browser: true }),
        commonjs({ sourcemap: true }),
        babel({
          extensions,
          babelHelpers: 'inline',
          include: ['src/**/*'],
          presets: [
            ['@babel/preset-typescript'],
            [
              '@babel/preset-env',
              {
                targets: { browsers: '> 2%, ie >= 11' },
                modules: false,
                spec: true,
                forceAllTransforms: true,
                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                corejs: { version: 3, proposals: false },
              },
            ],
          ],
          plugins: [
            ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { decoratorsBeforeExport: true }],
            ['@babel/proposal-class-properties'],
            ['@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread'],
            ['@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions'],
          ],
        }),
      ],
    };
```

```
    //tsconfig.json
    {
      "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "es6",
        "allowJs": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declarationDir": "./dist/types",
        "outDir": "./dist/tsc",
        "rootDir": "./src",
        "strict": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "noUnusedParameters": false,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "useDefineForClassFields": false,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "plugins": [
          {
            "name": "ts-lit-plugin",
            "strict": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "include": [
        "src/app.ts"],
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "out"
      ]
    }
```

```
    //app.ts
    import '@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs'
    import 'core-js/modules/es.global-this'
    import 'whatwg-fetch'
    import { SimpleElement }  from './simple-element'
    customElements.define("simple-element", SimpleElement);
    let simpleElement;
    window["simpleElement"] = () => simpleElement ? simpleElement : simpleElement = document.getElementById("simple-element");
```

```
    //simple-element.ts
    import { html, LitElement } from 'lit';
    import { property, customElement } from 'lit/decorators.js';

    @customElement("simple-element")
    export class SimpleElement extends LitElement {
      private _runMode: String = '';
      
      @property({ type: String })
      get runMode(){
        return this._runMode;
      }

      set runMode(rMode){
        const oldValue = this._runMode;
        this._runMode = rMode;
        this.requestUpdate("disabled", oldValue);
      }

      render() {
        return html`
          <div>
            This is from a simple element with param 
              <h2>${this.runMode}<h2>
          </div>
        `;
      }
    }
```

Could you please look into the details and provide some feedback to me?

Comment: This works fine with the old lit code.  Issue is with the first file - @lit\decorators\property.js.  With the old version, the code is working fine.

Comment: Not sure if this is the only issue, but at a quick glance the `@property` decorator should be on the setter rather than the getter. See https://lit.dev/docs/releases/upgrade/#decorated-getter

Comment: Thanks Augustine Kim, I changed @property to the setter, but that didn't solve the problem.  Changes I made to two methods:-
  get runMode(){
    return this._runMode;
  }
  
  @property({ type: String })
  set runMode(rMode){
    const oldValue = this._runMode;
    this._runMode = rMode;
    this.requestUpdate("disabled", oldValue);
  }

Comment: Issue resolved now.  There were a few files configuration had to be changed